# Unfortunately, AndroidTest has stopped

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

I was working on tutorials from this site
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSyy5TrUD5Q

I seems to work for the instructor but once I run it on the emulator it just says

Unfortunately, AndroidTest has stopped.

**Main Activity XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonTEST1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Button" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTEST1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
    android:ems="10" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Main Activity .java**

```
    package com.example.androidtest;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button button1;
EditText editText1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    button1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTEST1);
    editText1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTEST1);
    button1.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener)this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.buttonTEST1)
    {
        // Switching from screen to screen
        startActivity(new Intent(this, AndroidActivity2.class));

        editText1.setText("Button Tester Works");
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



    }
```

**LogCat**

```
   01-21 20:06:51.753: W/Trace(764): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-21 20:06:51.763: W/Trace(764): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-21 20:06:51.763: W/Trace(764): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-21 20:06:52.015: W/Trace(764): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-21 20:06:52.015: W/Trace(764): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-21 20:06:52.482: D/AndroidRuntime(764): Shutting down VM
01-21 20:06:52.482: W/dalvikvm(764): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
01-21 20:06:52.503: E/AndroidRuntime(764): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 20:06:52.503: E/AndroidRuntime(764): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidtest/com.example.androidtest.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.androidtest.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener
01-21 20:06:52.503: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-21 20:06:52.503: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-21 20:06:52.503: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-21 20:06:52.503: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-21 20:06:52.503: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-21 20:06:52.503: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-21 20:06:52.503: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-21 20:06:52.503: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 20:06:52.503: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-21 20:06:52.503: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-21 20:06:52.503: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-21 20:06:52.503: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-21 20:06:52.503: E/AndroidRuntime(764): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.androidtest.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener
01-21 20:06:52.503: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at com.example.androidtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
01-21 20:06:52.503: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-21 20:06:52.503: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-21 20:06:52.503: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-21 20:06:52.503: E/AndroidRuntime(764):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your Activity code as becuase you need to implement  `View.OnClickListener` in Activity to add `setOnClickListener` for Button

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener  {

Button button1;
EditText editText1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    button1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTEST1);
    editText1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTEST1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
}
//your code here
```

Comment: @user1998160 : see [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/extendsActivityimplementsOnClickListener.htm) example and press `CTRL + SHIFT + O` for importing all necessary packages

Comment: @user1998160 : most welcome friend. if this answer help u in solving current issue then mark it as answer for others help who is looking for same .

Answer (score 0):

You are not implementing `OnClickListener`(at least it is commented out) so your `onClick()`method won't help.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse your activity to a `OnClickListener`. However you haven't implemented it, because the code is commented out (with `/* ...  */`). 
Change

```
/*implements OnClickListener*/
```

to

```
implements OnClickListener
```

Comment: good suggestion but i still get the same error, it also made me add an abstract method will this change anything thanks for the help